# How can I fix my nav so when resized on small screens it has a burger menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

the end goal is for my navigation to look just like this:[image]
[image]

```html
  <div class="l-region l-region--navigation">
    <div data-mediasize="959" class="responsive-menus responsive-menus-0-0 absolute"><span class="toggler">☰ Menu</span><div id="block-superfish-1" class="block block--superfish block--superfish-1 responsive-menus-simple">
        <div class="block__content">
    <ul id="superfish-1" class="menu sf-menu sf-main-menu sf-horizontal sf-style-none sf-total-items-8 sf-parent-items-6 sf-single-items-2 superfish-processed sf-js-enabled sf-shadow"><li id="menu-2237-1" class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children"><a href="/event" class="sf-depth-1">Events</a></li>
```

link to code: https://jsfiddle.net/4b17u2fs/1/

Comment: You are looking for media queries. Search for hamburger menu.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't demonstrate the actual issue and the css is unreadable, read how to create a [mcve]

Comment: You can do that with CSS.

Comment: You can read more information here [How to Create Mobile Navigation Menu](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp)

Comment: @justDan how ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different @media queries for this.

With those media queries, you will be able to make your burger button visible or not. Then it's some javascript for the event when you click on the button.

You can do something like this :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    .burger-button {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

.burger-button {
   display: none;
}
```

This will only make your `.burger-button` visible on screens smaller than 1100px.

You just have to adjust things but this is the way of doing.

Comment: Try it by yourself, I'm here to learn you how it works ;) Try and let me know if you are having some issues. Besides that your `css` it not easily readable, it will be faster if you try it out.

Comment: I mean I have tried, multiple times but i am not getting anywhere

Comment: Can you please make a simple fiddle with a basic navigation bar? Create a simple one and test it in a small project, see what you can come up with..

Comment: Ok I will. Thanks